# Catalog URL Rewrites - Index product and categories URL rewrites - take long time to processing

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

How can i solve Catalog URL Rewrites not set,

Look for below image,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an amazing extension called "Dnd_Patchindexurl" which allows to solve this kind of problem.

Short story long, it reduces drastically the number of urls that need to be re-indexed. Works like a charm, it's a must have for me. Give it a try ;-)

http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove /var/session from FTP, and and do indexing from Terminal via SSH then it will fix
2. Check log file sometime uploaded one or two products may be cause this problem, check if there is any issue with products, delete that products and reindex and recreate that product.